# Populate spinner items from database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am having trouble to get the spinner to work properly with the items I retrieved from the SQLite database. I can get the items to show in the dropdown but I can't get them to be selected. If I replaced the items (questAddViewModel.categorylist) with a simple array of string then the spinner works properly. I just I can't figure out how to get the list populated from the database to work instead.

I am using the room and Dao for database call.

**Update:** Included screenshots for clarification. If I click on any of the item in the 2nd picture, the screen just goes back to 1st picture with nothing selected show up in the spinner. If I try to assign the selectedItem to a string as I am doing in the commented code

```
//questCategorySelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()
```

It will tell me it is null.

1. [ScreenShot with the Spinner (The Green Bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olKAi.png)
2. [ScreenShot with the Spinner showing the item in dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fmyp.png)

---

Here is my code for the spinner in the Fragment:

```
//Setup Spinner for Quest Category
        val categorySpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(application, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, questAddViewModel.categorylist) //
                categorySpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        binding.addQuestCategory.adapter = categorySpinnerAdapter
        binding.addQuestCategory.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
        {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {
                // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
                // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
                //questCategorySelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()
                //Toast.makeText(application, "${parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()} <-In Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // Another interface callback
            }
        }
```

Here is my Code in the ViewModel

```
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)
val categorylist = ArrayList<String>()

 init {
        populateCategorySpinner()
    }

    fun populateCategorySpinner()
    {
        uiScope.launch {
            populateCategorySpinnerList()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun populateCategorySpinnerList()
    {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
        {
            val categorylistcursor = database.getQuestCategoryCursor()

            if (categorylistcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val category =
                        categorylistcursor.getString(categorylistcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quest_category_name"))
                    categorylist.add(category);
                } while (categorylistcursor.moveToNext())
            }
            categorylistcursor.close();
        }
    }
```

This is what I have in the Dao

```
    @Query ( "SELECT * FROM t_ql_quest_category")
    fun getQuestCategoryCursor(): Cursor
```

I am looking for a solution to get the list I retrieve from the database cursor to be able to get selected in the spinner properly.

Comment: What's the real problem: Toast is not shown or questCategorySelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() is wrong?

Comment: it seems like the program never make it to the onItemSelected when I use the list from the database. Therefore I always get a null value on the selectedItem when i try to call it. I can see the list in dropdown but the item I click in the dropdown is not showing on the spinner after i click as well.

Comment: I never use ViewModel, but try defining questCategorySelected = (TextView)view . That could help

Comment: questCategorySelected  is a string I defined. I tried to use it to see if I get any value back at all when I select an item. It returns null. I have updated the question to include this information. Thanks!. The full code works as soon as I replace the list from the database list to an array I defined in the fragment. I am trying to figure out what I did wrong to get the database list to fit into the ArrayAdapter or to understand if this is even possible at all.

Comment: Hello Rex, welcome to StackOverflow! I think you may want to include a little bit more code (the adapter!) to determine what's going on there. You may want to tell us a little bit more about what you have debugged. Seems like you're using DataBinding, add this information to the question, for it may have implications.

Comment: Where in your fragment are you initializing this adapter? You should pass an immutable copy of the data to your adapter, not the direct reference stored in the ViewModel though. The way I see this, when your VM initializes, it calls a suspending coroutine, this is asynchronous so, I'm interested in knowing when is your fragment assuming the data is there and populating the adapter's source. Debug this, and watch the contents of your list, are you losing the references?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. This gives me a good direction to look and I was able to solve my issue using LiveData. I have the adapter in the onCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change
questCategorySelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()

By

questCategorySelected = (TextView) view

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments and answer. I actually figured this out after reading the comments. It seems like the problem is due to the array is actually not populated with the data due to the coroutine call to the database. It was confusing because it was showing up in the dropdown list. I resolved the problem after reading a bit more on LiveData and keep the Adapter updated observing it. I tried several ways to pass the array to Fragment from ViewModel but seems like without using LiveData, the list always got lost due to database call coroutine. If anyone have better way of doing this, suggestions are welcomed! Thanks!

Below is my solution:

Fragment

```
//Setup Spinner for Quest Category with LiveData monitoring of the Category List
        var CategoryArray: Array<String>
        var categorySpinnerAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

        questAddViewModel.categorylist.observe(this, Observer
        {if (it != null && it.isNotEmpty()) {
            CategoryArray = toArray(questAddViewModel.categorylist.value!!)
            categorySpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(application, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CategoryArray) //
            categorySpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            binding.addQuestCategory.adapter = categorySpinnerAdapter
        }})

        binding.addQuestCategory.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
        {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {
                // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
                // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // Another interface callback
            }
        }
```

ViewModel

```
private val _categorylist = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>()
    val categorylist: LiveData<ArrayList<String>>
        get() = _categorylist

 private suspend fun populateCategorySpinnerList()
    {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO)
        {
            val categorylistcursor = database.getQuestCategoryCursor()
            val categorylistfromdb = ArrayList<String>()

            if (categorylistcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val category =
                        categorylistcursor.getString(categorylistcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quest_category_name"))
                    categorylistfromdb.add(category);
                } while (categorylistcursor.moveToNext())
            }
            categorylistcursor.close();
            _categorylist.postValue(categorylistfromdb)
        }
    }
```